# CodeIgniter's dbutils not recognizing new database connection

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

Does the [Utility Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/utilities.html) reconnect to the database defined in your database configuration file when it's initialized?

The following code is returning databases from the dev database and not prod:

```
$this->load->database('prod');
$this->load->dbutil();
print_r($this->dbutil->list_databases());
```

My database configuration file contains:

```
$db['dev']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['dev']['username'] = 'root';
$db['dev']['password'] = '';
$db['dev']['database'] = 'mydb';
...

$db['prod']['hostname'] = 'prodhost';
$db['prod']['username'] = 'username';
$db['prod']['password'] = 'password';
$db['prod']['database'] = 'myproddb';
...
```

**edit 1:** indeed, dbutil appears to be influenced by $active_group variable in the database configuration file. How do I override this for a single function? I thought that was the purpose of `$this->load->database('environment');` ... no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Utility class uses the database assigned to $this->db to carry out its functions.

The solution was to assign the result of `$this->load->database('environment')` to `$this->db`:

```
$this->db = $this->load->database('environment', TRUE);
```